# Docker - cannot launch iis

Tags: docker, iis

I am currently doing a tutorial on how to use Docker.
I am using windows 10.
I have installed IIS in the Docker Command Line prompt, and when I type docker ps I can see a container Id, an Image of "microsoft/iis", a command of "C:\ServiceMonitor..." and some other details.
I type 
c:>docker inspect (Container Id) and I get the IP Address from the Networks node.
In my browser I enter http://(IP Address) which should bring up IIS.
But instead it times out.
So what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: are you able to ping to the ipadress? and let me know the ipaddress

Comment: Yes I can ping the IP address

Comment: Please include the Dockerfile and whatever command you are using to run it in your post.

Comment: I mention in my question  that I am trying to run http://{IP Address} in my IE browser but it times out. I get the IP Address from the CMD prompt by typing; C:\> docker inspect 6c

Comment: If you are able to ping the IP address then there could be two reasons for failure. 1) host port not mapped to the docker port of IIS or 2) IIS is not running successfully inside the docker - run 'docker logs' command to see the state of IIS process.